# Plotting the Kepler stars

Tags: graphing-functions

**Kepler Field of View**

I'm looking for a way to take stellar coordinates (right ascension / declination) and plot them, so that they look like the picture below.

[image: Kepler projection]

This is what I have now:

[image: Normal stellar projection]

The trick here, is that I'd like the Kepler's field of view (those little squares) to remain squares, rotated and distorted appropriately.

A normal stellar projection (e.g. [from here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52936/plotting-a-stars-position-on-a-2d-map)) look great, but results in distorted squares, as shown in the second picture.

Any thoughts about how to plot this correctly?